# Javascript: Display:none for ID A, if ID B is not there

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a javascript function that says if an element with id="a" is not on the page, Then an element with id="b" should not be shown.

This is what I came up with but is not working:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("idb");
  if(document.getElementById("ida")){
  x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
  x.style.display = "none";
 }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Dumb question here, but can you verify that this function is even running?

Comment: `document.getElementById("ida")` implies `id="ida"`, not `id="a"`. Please try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser.

Comment: @Xufox yes, I know that. I just used that for example purposes only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `length` property with `querySelectorAll()`:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("idb");
  if(document.querySelectorAll("#ida").length > 0){
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
 }
}

myFunction();
```

```css
#idb{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="idb">idb</div>
<div id="ida">ida</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not there:

```
document.getElementById("ida") == null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.body.contains` among many other ways to do this, so a simple solution would be like this (you put it inside a function):

```
a = document.getElementById("a");
b = document.getElementById("b");
if(document.body.contains(a)){
    b.style.visibility = "visible"; 
} else {
 b.style.visibility = "hidden"; 
}
```

Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ax5gx8qj/5/).

Answer (score 0):

For one you don't need to include "id" if your id = "a" because you are specifying that already in your get element by id. Same with id b so it would be more like this:

```
function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("b");
   if(document.getElementById("a")){
      x.style.display = "block";
   } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
   }
}
```